# `Feedback` text not shown in bot conversation

Tags: botframework

My formflow dialog contains a field with custom validation applied...

```
 var form = builder
    .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(UserName))
    .SetActive(state => string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.UserName)))
    .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(ValuationOption))
        .SetPrompt(new PromptAttribute($"Hello {{UserName}}.<br /><br />Are you looking to get an price estimate for a car you’re selling, or for a car you’re looking to buy? {{||}}")))
    .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(RegistrationNumber))
        .SetDefine(RegistrationNumberDefinitionMethod))
    .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(Mileage))
                    .SetValidate(async (state, value) =>
                        {
                            var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = value };

                            if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int mileage))
                            {
                                result.IsValid = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                result.Feedback = "That isn't valid number. Can you enter it again please?";
                                result.IsValid = false;
                            }

                            return await Task.FromResult(result);
                        }))
    .Field(nameof(PreviousOwnerOption),
        active: carValuationDialog => carValuationDialog.ValuationOption == ValuationOptions.LookingToSell)
    .Field(nameof(ServiceHistoryOption),
        active: carValuationDialog => carValuationDialog.ValuationOption == ValuationOptions.LookingToSell)
    .Confirm(Confirmation)
    .OnCompletion(GetValuationAndDisplaySummaryToUser);
```

When `SetValidate()` executes, and the given mileage value is not an `int`, the `result.Feedback = ...` line is executed. However, instead of seeing the message "That isn't a valid mileage value. Can you enter it again please?" I see this...

[image]

Full discolsure, I do have the following attribute declared on the dialog class

`[Template(TemplateUsage.NotUnderstood, "Sorry, I don't understand '{0}'.")]`

but I thought the `result.Feedback` text would be shown to the user in this case? Not using the `Template[]` results in the following text displayed when the user enters an invalid mileage...

> "d" is not a car mileage option.

Which looks rubbish, and is why I used the `Template[]` override.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**
I was able to accomplish this by applying templates to the fields themselves for validation.  This should be the exact behavior you are looking for.  Note that I did not do extensive testing, I just wanted to get the general idea working.  Heres the code I used:

```
[Serializable]
public class SandwichOrder
{
    //public PreviousOwnerOptions Options;
    [Template(TemplateUsage.NotUnderstood, "Sorry, I don't understand '{0}'.")]
    [Prompt("What is the {&}?")]
    public int Mileage;

    [Template(TemplateUsage.NotUnderstood, "Sorry, This is not valid '{0}'.")]
    [Prompt("How many {&}?")]
    public int Days;


    public static IForm<SandwichOrder> BuildForm()
    {
        var form = new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
            .Field(new FieldReflector<SandwichOrder>(nameof(Mileage))
                .SetValidate(async (state, value) =>
                {
                    var result = new ValidateResult {IsValid = true, Value = value};

                    if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int mileage))
                    {
                        result.IsValid = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.IsValid = false;
                    }

                    return await Task.FromResult(result);
                }))
            .Field(new FieldReflector<SandwichOrder>(nameof(Days))
            .SetValidate(async (state, value) =>
            {
                var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = value };

                if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int days))
                {
                    result.IsValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.IsValid = false;
                }

                return await Task.FromResult(result);
            }));
        return form.Build();
    }
}
```

This produced this result:

[image]

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's not the template attribute that is causing me an issue, it's the fact that the text I provide to `result.Feedback` isn't displayed to the user when validation fails. Even when I remove the `Template` attribute entirely, the feedback text still isn't shown, instead I get `"d" is not a car mileage option.` if I enter "d" as a mileage value. It seems the `.Feedback` property is ignored.

Comment: I get that and instead of using the feedback property, you can use the method I presented to achieve the same result you are looking for.  Is the Template override working for you?  That would be news to me

Comment: Configuring the template using your approach worked. Not sure why the `Template[]` does not work for you, but does for me. However, you're going to get mad at me now, I need to pad out my question because I've missed out a key bit of detail. There is more than one property associated with this dialog, which means if I enter a unknown answer to any other question, they too will also get "That isn't valid number. Can you enter it again please?" in response. Sorry about that. I'll edit my question.

Comment: That makes sense, seems like a completely reasonable use case. I will look into this more today and see if I can come up with something else that will do what you need.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It's been incredibly useful.

Comment: Edited my answer, this should work for you.  Turns out templates are actually working.  I have had some struggles with them in the past.  Good luck.

Comment: That worked first time for me. Thanks so much for your help, that was brilliant.

Comment: If you have a moment, any chance you can take a peek at this please? [How to stop formflow dialog from re-prompting user when validation fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169968/how-to-stop-formflow-dialog-from-re-prompting-user-when-validation-fails)