# How to stop formflow dialog from re-prompting user when validation fails?

Tags: botframework

I have a formflow dialog in which one of it's properties is this...

```
[Describe("Car Mileage")]
[Prompt("Cool! What's the mileage of the car?")]
[Template(TemplateUsage.NotUnderstood, "Sorry, I didn't understand that mileage value. Can you enter it again please?")]
public string Mileage { get; set; }
```

Ignore the `[Template(TemplateUsage.NotUnderstood,...` for now, I'll come back to that.

The dialog is built using the following...

```
var form = builder
    .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(ValuationOption))
        .SetPrompt(new PromptAttribute($"Hi.<br /><br />Are you looking to get a value for a car you're selling, or car you're buying? {{||}}")))
    .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(RegistrationNumber))
        .SetDefine(RegistrationNumberDefinitionMethod))
    .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(Mileage))
        .SetValidate(async (state, value) =>
            {
                var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = value };

                var regex = new Regex("[0-9,]+");
                var match = regex.Match((string)value);

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    result.IsValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Feedback = "Sorry, I didn't understand that.";
                    result.IsValid = false;
                }

                return await Task.FromResult(result);
            }))
    .Field(
        nameof(PreviousOwnerOption),
        active: carValuationDialog => carValuationDialog.ValuationOption == ValuationOptions.LookingToSell)
    .Field(
        nameof(ServiceHistoryOption),
        active: carValuationDialog => carValuationDialog.ValuationOption == ValuationOptions.LookingToSell)
    .Confirm(Confirmation)
    .OnCompletion(GetValuationAndDisplaySummaryToUser);

return form.Build();
```

This question is related to

[`Feedback` text not shown in bot conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136774/feedback-text-not-shown-in-bot-conversation)

I'm experimenting with the validation for `Mileage`, as I've changed that property from `int` to `string` in order to allow freeflow text e.g. "23,456 miles". As a side-effect of changing the data type, when the validation for `Mileage` fails, I get the following...

[image]

Not only does the `result.Feedback` value now get shown to the user (it did not before, when `Mileage` was an `int`), which is fine, but also the original question text is shown.

So my main question is - what can I do so that when validation fails, the original question prompt is not shown to the user?

As a side note, when changing `Mileage` back to `int`, and the validation fails (`result.IsValid = false`), `result.Feedback` is not shown, but `[Template(TemplateUsage.NotUndderstood....` is now shown. So it seems the type of the property matters in relation to what validation messages are shown.

Comment: `what can I do so that when validation fails, the original question prompt is not shown to the user?` Do you want that bot does not prompt the original question when validations failed within field validation?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I do not want the original question shown when validation fails.

Comment: Ahh FormFlow you are such a fickle creation

Comment: @JasonSowers lol. Based on your last comment, I'm assuming I might be up poo creek with this one?

Comment: OK, what were going to do is simply reword the mileage question so that it can be used multiple times without seeming out of context. Not a massive issue for us in this case.